# Как сделать проверку на css свойство в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать проверку на css свойство в jQuery? То есть когда round будет 450px выводить `alert('error')`

```js
var round = $('.round');
  $(document).ready(function() {
    round.animate({
      width: '450px',
      height: '450px',
    },
  5000);
  });
if(round.is('450px')) {
  alert('error');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() { // Same as $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.round').animate({
    width: '450px',
    height: '450px',
  }, 5000, function () {
    alert('error');
  });
});
```